# Is my React Native Android project's intent incorrect? It differs that the intent of a fresh React Native project

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I have a React Native Android application that sends this intent on app build

```
{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.app.debug/com.test.app.MainActivity }
```

However, on a fresh React Native project, the intent looks like this:

```
{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.app.debug/.MainActivity }
```

As you can see `com.test.app` is missing before `.MainActivity` in the second example and I am wondering why is it appended?

Comment: if Activity is inside other package than application package, then it have to have full path. If Activity is in the same package or in subpackage, the only subpackage path is needed. In your example first one have full path as activity is not in subpackage of application, while in second one it tells system by starting with dot, to look for given activity in com.test.app.debug.MainActivity (activity path is appended to application package)